# How to create a shortcode for custom page template

Tags: shortcode, page-template

I have a custom page template and I want it to display on specific pages. The only way I know to do this is to create a shortcode for this custom page template, so that I can use the custom page template by using shortcode. But I don't know how doing this.

I saw some article about this, but I forgot the website link.

How to create a shortcode for custom page template?

Comment: What you are asking doesn't really make sense. Can you please provide more detail?

Comment: @s_ha_dum, what i need is, to create a shortcode for custom page tempate

Comment: Yes. Repeating the same thing you wrote before increases clarity a great deal.

Comment: I think you need a shortcode to call a template part to include that part inside a page content, is that right?

Comment: yes. my snippet below is correct?

Comment: although I followed the above steps, it gives the following error: Template: invalid template name Please help me to fix this

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/251618)

Answer (score 7):

I solved now, by adding this snippet in `functions.php`

```
function my_form_shortcode() {
   ob_start();
   get_template_part('my_form_template');
   return ob_get_clean();   
} 
add_shortcode( 'my_form_shortcode', 'my_form_shortcode' );
```

Comment: hats off.. a genius hack wordpress..

Comment: @user3818821, what is the my_form_template? is this template ID?

Answer (score 1):

I solved using below method.

Using Plugin (**Shortcodes Ultimate**) we can create or make shortcode for  wordpress custom page template.

1. create your custom page template without including header and footer.
2. Install the plugin(**find link below**) into wordpress site.
3. Activate it.
4. Go to plugin **Shortcodes Ultimate › Available shortcodes**.
5. You can find the variety of filter options in that click **Other** will find **Template** open that.
6. In shortcode section add the name of your custom template(**[su_template name="name-of-your-template.php"]**) with or without php extentions.
7. Use template file name (with optional .php extension). If you need to use templates from theme sub-folder, use relative path. Example values: page, page.php, includes/page.php
8. Now copy the whole shortcode and paste it into the page or post you want.

Plugin download link

[Shortcodes Ultimate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/)

Answer (score 1):

I find [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/shortcode-in-a-template/) one is the easiest way:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); ?>
```

Comment: This question is about how to add a new shortcode, not use one.